# Can Margin be enforced even with Dock property set?

Tags: winforms, controls, margin, dock, groupbox

I have a WinForms `Form` with a few controls on it. All of them are `GroupBox` controls and I want them stacked, with a vertical margin set between them. I have set the `Dock` property to Top and it stacks them alright, but ignores the margin (controls are as close to each other as they can be).

**Can these margins still somehow be enforced?** Basically, it would calculate the regular docked position (as if the margin was 0) then apply the margin. Is something like this possible?

The other way I've tried this is with `FlowLayoutPanel` with `TopDown` option. However, then I need to manually set the size and Left/Right anchors.

Is there any easy way to acomplish this scenario or should I stick with what I already have?

Comment: Try using `Padding` instead of `Margin` when the control is docked.

Comment: Yes, FLP required.  Set the Margin property on the controls inside it to create the gap.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The set docking property will ignore your padding properties between GroupBox controls, so yes, your best bet is the Flow or Table panels to do this.

Answer (score 39):

Place each GroupBox in a Panel, Set Panel Dock Property to Top, Group Box Dock Property to Fill. Then set Padding on the panels.

Comment: Padding is the key! At least in my case.

Comment: It's a shame that docking is not taking `Margin` into account.. Naming all those `Panels` can be a nightmare.

Answer (score 8):

Add a dummy transparent panel docked between each textbox with a height equal to the exact distance you require.