# How to set vertical gap when DockStyle is set as Top in Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have one Panel, I have set the DockStyle as Top but I want to set start location like ( 0, 10), means I want to start this panel from 10 position down from the top. I have tried Padding and Margin but not working, changing the DockStyle also not working.

```
this.panel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top;
        this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 10);
```

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057868/can-margin-be-enforced-even-with-dock-property-set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add padding to the control that contains `panel1`, not to the panel itself:

```
// using "this" assuming you're in a form that directly contains panel1
this.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0, 10, 0, 0);
panel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top;
```